# Java how can I avoid recursion in equals and hashCode methods for objects with references to each other

Tags: java, recursion

I was making a java library, and I came a problem similar to this: objects of class Foo are primarily storage for objects of class Bar, but also some other data. Bar objects store various data, including a reference to the Foo object that created it (note: Foo and Bar are both immutable)

```
class Foo {

  private final Bar[] bars;

  public Foo(int length) {
    this.bars = new Bar[length];
    for (int i = 0; i < bars.length; i++) bars[i] = new Bar(this);
  }

}

class Bar {

  public final Foo foo;

  public Bar(Foo foo) {
    this.foo = foo;
  }

}
```

This is all well and good, but when I tried to make equals and hashCode methods, I found that since Foo.bars is fundamental to the identity of a Foo object and Bar.foo is fundamental to the identity of a Bar object, Bar.equals called Foo.equals, and Foo.equals called Bar.equals (indirectly via java.util.Arrays.equals), and the same for hashCode. This is obviously infinitely recursive, and hence must be changed. My question is this: is there a way to avoid this other than making one ignore the other in terms of equality? If not, how should I choose which one should ignore the other?

Comment: I would really question why you need the instance of `Foo` in `Bar`.

Comment: Any modern IDE should be able to generate the `equals` and `hashcode` methods for you and therefore you can let the IDE do the thinking. intelliJ IDEA can generate these for you fully implemented.

Comment: The problem that you have a circular dependencies. If you remove this then you can write an implementation.

Comment: Bar has a reference of a Foo because Bars are fundamentally a part of a whole, and as such a having a Bar without knowing what Foo it belongs to is almost entirely useless.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution for `equals()` is to short-circuit by comparing identity first:

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o == this) {
        return true;
    }
    // check type and fields etc.
}
```

Comment: But what about hashCode? You can't really have one without the other.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth True, but it's hard to offer a solution to that without a more concrete example. As it stands, neither class contains any meaningful fields.